Why is homological algebra nonconstructive?
In the Introduction to Weibel's homological algebra book, he states that homological algebra gives nonconstructive results. He doesn't elaborate on this further, so I wanted to know where exactly the obstruction to being constructible is.
For a concrete example, is Riemann-Roch 'constructible'? More specifically, if using RR we calculate the dimension of the space of global sections of a bundle, then can we go back through the proof and explicitly construct a basis? If not, where exactly lies the problem?
Also I have a related general question: Is this kind of nonconstructibility all essentially from the axiom of choice?

Homological algebra is really not a topic directly related to topology. Is the book really referring to that, or to homology of topological spaces?

In the very same paragraph he gives an example of what he means.

I'm going to conversationally discuss just one example of what Weibel means. There are very many, but I hope you'll get the point.
Really, we mean "non-explicit" moreso than we mean non-constructive, since in principle one could backtrack through most proofs and in principle 'construct' a map by demonstrating, in full, it exists.. but sometimes we truly mean nonconstructive in the sense that the axiom of choice is involved. For instance in any proof that requires free subgroups of an Abelian group to be free, as in the universal coefficient theorems - it's true, but you cannot exactly do it by hand, in the same way that I know $\Bbb R$ has a $\Bbb Q$-basis but I could not write it down for you.

A lot of results and constructions speak of things... "up to isomorphism". You will really feel this once you get to derived functors; the whole thing is utterly non-constructive in its total generality. For one must choose injective resolutions for each and every object, and while you know that it can be done the procedure is rather abstract and very quickly, in generality, becomes impossible to really carry out by hand.
It goes something like this (working with $R$-modules, $R$ a commutative unital ring, for simplicity): start with an $R$-module $M$, embed $M\hookrightarrow J$ for an injective module $J$. Ok, what even is $J$? One possible construction, outlined by Weibel on page $42$, is to take $J:=\prod_{\hom_R(M;\hom_\Bbb Z(R;\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z))}\hom_\Bbb Z(R;\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$. I would almost never want to actually work out what all those "homs" are, and you can't really "do" this for a general $R$-module $M$. But it gets worse, because that was only the first step... Now what I do is I "compute" the cokernel of the canonical map $M\to J$. Again, I would almost never want to do this, but abstractly I know it is possible. I set $M_1:=\mathrm{coker}(M\to J)$, and then I rinse and repeat; define $J^1$ to be $\prod_{\hom_R(M_1;\hom_\Bbb Z(R;\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z))}\hom_\Bbb Z(R;\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$ and take $M_2:=\mathrm{coker}(M_1\to J^1)$. So far I have an exact sequence $0\to M\to J\to J^1\to M_2\to0$, and I extend it by embedding $M_2\hookrightarrow J^2$, $J^2$ injective, and keep going.
But even in a low dimension like $2$, I haven't the foggiest what $M_2$ is. Even if you give me a really simple initial module $M$. I just know that it is possible. Now to compute the derived functor, let's say $\mathsf{Ext}(N;-)$, I take the cohomology of $\hom(N,J)\to\hom(N,J^1)\to\hom(N,J^2)\to\cdots$ and (i) I barely understand what the terms of this complex even are (!!) and (ii) taking the cohomology will make this even harder.
However, the beautiful thing about homological algebra is that the above criticisms don't really matter. I can still prove a lot about the functor $\mathsf{Ext}(N;-)$; I could prove some Ext modules are isomorphic to some other Ext modules, I can make arguments and use it in other proofs, making perhaps some syzygy arguments for the computation of some other thing, but all this is horribly nonconstructive - for a loose sense of the word nonconstructive, let's not mention formal logic here. One would really struggle to write down, using the injective resolution definition, an explicit function witnessing the isomorphism $\mathsf{Ext}_\Bbb Z(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. I know it exists, and I can argue for it, but the full argument is going to use a lot of other isomorphisms one would never wish to construct by hand and the resulting map from one group to the other group (modelling the left hand side as the cohomology of $\hom(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,J)\to\hom(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,J^1)\to\hom(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z,J^2)\to\cdots$) is infeasible.
This is, by the way, a simple example. But hopefully it is enough; once you do enough homological algebra you really see what Weibel means here. Minor caveat: a lot of the time we can use "canonical" resolutions - Weibel talks about this in more detail in the later chapters concerning simplicial methods. Nevertheless, working everything out on the explicit point-set level is not a thing you can really do.
If you know a bit of algebraic topology then maybe it helps to consider this: I know that $H^2_{\mathsf{sing}}(S^2)\cong\Bbb Z$, but I'll be damned if I could explicitly construct a generator for you. Consider I have to map every single $2$-chain to an integer, and make a definition for these - even for ones which aren't cycles. I mean, I maybe could, but it would be hard and take a lot of time and moreover $S^2$ is very simple. I know it is possible but I really, really don't want to do it; e.g. consider the highly nonconstructive nature of the universal coefficient theorem comparing homology and cohomology. We use a "splitting" which must exist because a subgroup of a free group is again free but no one could write this down. And once I started giving you examples whose computation invokes excision, the barycentric subdivision lemma, abstract boundary homomorphisms in a long exact sequence etc. etc. this quickly becomes even more difficult. Harder statements like the Thom isomorphism also don't really 'construct' the relevant cohomology class, in the sense that no one is going to write down an explicit map $\text{formal n-chains}\to\Bbb Z$, but we nevertheless know it exists.

The other answer focuses on "informal" and "loose" meanings of non-constructiveness. I want to add that homological algebra with its reliance on injective and projective modules is also very much non-constructive in the formal sense of "relying on some form of the axiom of choice".
In fact, Andreas Blass proved that there is a model of ZF where there is no non-zero injective abelian group whatsoever.
Although we can explicitly write down candidates for injective modules such as $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ over $\Bbb Z$, proving that they are actually injective requires some form of choice.
We also can't prove that free modules are projective without choice or that there are enough projective abelian groups.

Can you add the paper ref by Andreas Blass?

@MartinBrandenburg it's called Injectivity, projectivity, and the axiom of choice

A third answer, related to that of @FShrike: spectral sequences. I suggest that often the whole point of a spectral sequence is that it is, loosely speaking, nonconstructive. I mean that if you understood everything involved in the construction of a typical spectral sequence, you wouldn't have to use the spectral sequence because you already understand everything.
For example, a typical spectral sequence arises from a filtered chain complex, and the abutment is the homology of that chain complex: that's what you're trying to understand. You filter the chain complex according to some recipe, and that induces a filtration on its homology, and it also yields a spectral sequence by taking the homology of the associated graded chain complex. This associated graded chain complex is supposed to be easier to understand, and so you can compute the $E_1$- or $E_2$-page, but the differentials and the $E_\infty$-page are not so accessible. To understand those, you really need to understand the filtration and the original chain complex (and its homology), but if you understood those things, you likely wouldn't be using the spectral sequence in the first place.
(There are instances where what I'm saying is not true, but those are the exception rather than the rule.)
